# sleep without freezing gui vb6

Tags: vb6, time-wait

I need to wait for some events in my application, or wait for somew time to elaps before doing some other stuff

i tried this pseudo code in vb6

```
starttime=gettickcount
do
endtime=gettickcount
if endtime-starttime=>waittime then exit do
doevents()
loop
```

But this seems to freezes the gui, i need an alternative method that will wait without freez the gui

EDIT i forgot the doevents, please take note

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using a timer.  A timer fire off an event whenever it reaches it's tick count.  So you could tell something to fire every 3 seconds, 3 minutes, 1 hour, etc.

The timer will run in the background allowing your app to continue functioning as normal while it counts down.

Comment: +1 - this is the correct answer.  You shouldn't stay inside an event handler any longer than you have to.  If you need to do something later, then use a `Timer` to raise an event at the appropriate time.  Never sit in a tight loop because you're blocking the GUI thread, so you're not letting it repaint.

Comment: @Scott so in an object event_handler, i have to wait, and you say i should use a timer? how do i do this

Comment: Here is a simple example:http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-timer-control-vb6

Answer (score 1):

Add "DoEvents" in your vb6 code... it allows the app to repaint...

Comment: Just adding DOevents to code without truly understanding why you need it and the implications of it is a recipe for +very+ subtle problems later on. Doevents will yield, which means that other events in your app can fire, which means that other routines in your app, which you may have never intended to be reintrant can in fact be reentered, which can cause all sorts of problems.